# How to make file readable and editable when serialize object to xml by C++

Tags: c++, xml, qt, serialization

I am using Qt C++ for desktop software development and have lots of config files to save and read. I'm now using QDataStream to save config object to binary file. It works to some extent, but the file saved can't read directly ,meanwhile, when I change the class member, then old file will not able to be parsed to object.
So I'm wondering that, If there any method can fulfill the requirements below?

1. can save object to a xml file and parse a xml file to an object.
2. the xml file can be edit by any text editor manually
3. when class definition modified,file generate by old class,can also parsed correctly.

I knew some realizations by C# which match fields name with xml node by reflection.Is there any similar framework in C++?

Comment: What you seem to be looking for is called [*serialization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). And there are libraries and frameworks that can help you with that. I don't know Qt that well, but I'll guess they already have that functionality.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, it's about serialization, but more than serialization I think. I can serialize and deserialize  an object .but the more I want is ,the file generated can be readable and editable by text editor like "notepad","notepad++".

Comment: Some serialization frameworks can use different file-formats. The most common being a pure binary format, XML and JSON. You should look at some frameworks and see what they support.

Comment: You might want to look at something like [cereal](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/serialization_archives.html).

Answer (score 0):

The Oops library is designed for serializing C++ datastructures to human readable and editable files. It does not support XML because it is too verbose, but 3 other file formats: text, yaml, and binary.
https://bitbucket.org/barczpe/oops/src/master
https://bitbucket.org/barczpe/oops/wiki/Home